# OpenGL arrangement of normal data in VBOs

Tags: opengl, vbo

When reading examples of simple VBOs programs I've noticed there seems to be an association of normal data with vertex data. But from the definition of a normal, I would have thought that the normal data should be associated with the face data.

From the code segment below I can noticed that the normal data for each MyVertex is the same, so the normal for the "triangle face" would make sense. But I am unsure of how one would store the normal data for larger objects where several faces may share the same vertices as stored in GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER.

Questions: 
How does OpenGL conceptually handle the normal data? Or have I made a wrong assumption in how normals should work somewhere?

(code below from http://www.opengl.org/wiki/VBO_-_just_examples)

```
struct MyVertex
  {
    float x, y, z;        //Vertex
    float nx, ny, nz;     //Normal
    float s0, t0;         //Texcoord0
  };

  MyVertex pvertex[3];
  //VERTEX 0
  pvertex[0].x = 0.0;
  pvertex[0].y = 0.0;
  pvertex[0].z = 0.0;
  pvertex[0].nx = 0.0;
  pvertex[0].ny = 0.0;
  pvertex[0].nz = 1.0;
  pvertex[0].s0 = 0.0;
  pvertex[0].t0 = 0.0;
  //VERTEX 1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where's the rest of the code section?

Comment: It's in the link, I wasn't sure if I should have posted a large block of code int he question itself

Answer (score 2):

In OpenGL, normals are vector attributes, just like position or texture coordinates.

Having per-face normals may seem reasonable, but wouldn't work in practice.

Reason: One triangle is physically flat, but is often an approximation of a curved surface. Having normal vectors different among the vertices of a triangle allows you to interpolate between them to get an approximated normal vector at *any* point of the surface.

Think of a vertex normal as a sample of the normal at some particular points of a smooth surface.

(Of course, when rendering surfaces with hard edges, like a cube, the above doesn't really help and many require you to have duplicate vertices differing only by the normal.)